# Newton method and machine learning

Tags: newton-raphson

There is some debate about why Newton method is not widely used in machine learning. Instead, people tend to use gradient descent.

- Some people claim that Newton method is not used because it [involves the second derivative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253632/why-is-newtons-method-not-widely-used-in-machine-learning). How so? Indirectly?   Why? Doesn't Newton method neglect the second derivative?
- Is there a name for [Newton's method with cubic convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624361/newtons-method-with-cubic-convergence-three-taylor-terms-instead-of-two)?
- Can we claim that Newton's method is a form of gradient descent?

Comment: Newton's method for root finding does not need a second derivative; Newton's method for _optimisation_ is root-finding on the derivative, and so needs a second derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In machine learning, the interest in solving function-is-$0$ conditions is for, say, minimizing $f$ by setting $\nabla f=0$. Since this is already a first derivative, Newton's method ends up using the second derivative $\nabla^2 f$, which is very expensive in high dimensions.

The cubic approach you linked looks unfamiliar. I was hoping it'd be [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method), but it seems different.

Newton's method isn't considered a form of gradient descent, because GD doesn't choose its step size to approximate the root. Newton's method is quadratically convergent, which is a bit of a double-edged sword; GD prefers a slower but somewhat safer linear convergence.